# Equivalent statement of Weierstrass approximation theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, weierstrass-approximation

> Let $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb C$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$.
> Then there exists a sequence $\{p_n\}$ of polynomials such that $$p_n\to f \text{ uniformly on }[a,b] \;\;\;(1)$$
> Equivalently, for all $\varepsilon>0 $ there exists a polynomial $P$ such that $$\|P-f\|_{\infty}<\varepsilon \;\;\; (2)$$

I want to show that two conclusions are equivalent.

Suppose  there exists a sequence $\{p_n\}$ of polynomials such that $$p_n\to f \text{ uniformly on }[a,b]$$
Then for all $\varepsilon>0\;\; \exists n\in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall n>N$,$|p_n(x)-f(x)|< \varepsilon$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. How to choose polynomial $P$ in $(2)$ that can satisfies the second conclusion?

Conversely, If $(2)$ holds, can I just choose $p_n=P\;\; \forall n\in \Bbb N$, so that $(1)$ hold?

Comment: *Hint:* How is $\|P-f\|_\infty$ defined?

Comment: $\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|P(x)-f(x)|$

Comment: Correct. So $|p_n(x)-f(x)|< \varepsilon$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ is equivalent to $\|p_n-f\|_\infty < \epsilon$. Does that help?

Comment: If I choose $p_N$, I'm wondering if the $\varepsilon>0$ change this $N$ will change as well. So I can not choose this $p_N$ to be $P$, is that right?

Comment: If (2) holds, take $p_n$ with $\|p_n-f\|_\infty<1/n$.

Comment: But for every $n\in \Bbb N$ we have $p_n=P$, or I have  misunderstand something.

Comment: @StevenLu: There seems to be some misunderstanding. Note that he polynomial $P$ in (2) can depend on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do it.